# Dynamically size arrow \mapsto in function definition

Tags: math-mode, symbols, horizontal-alignment

I have the following diagram:

[image: Diagram]

However, this looks a bit ugly, I would like a version that looks a little bit better. For example, size the last arrow such that the T_\phi is moved to the right.

This is the code which I am using to do this:

```
\begin{align*}
  \xi \colon &\lb \to \mathcal{L}(\hh)\\
  &\phi \mapsto T_\phi.
\end{align*}
```

Where `\lb` and `\hh` just give the names for those spaces. Does anybody have a suggestion how I would improve the look of this function definition?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Personaly, I think it is better to use:

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
  \xi \colon L^\infty(T) &\to \mathcal{L}(H^2)\\
  \phi &\mapsto T_\phi.
\end{align*}
```

Anyway, you can obtain what you want through

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\phantomarrow[2]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle #1\to$}%
  \hbox to \wd0{%
    $#2\mapstochar
     \cleaders\hbox{$\mkern-1mu\relbar\mkern-3mu$}\hfill
     \mkern-7mu\rightarrow$}%
  \,}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \xi \colon &L^\infty(T) \to \mathcal{L}(H^2)\\
  &\phantomarrow{L^\infty(T)}{\phi} T_\phi.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You're right, the first suggestion looks the best (at least to me). I will try to figure out how the second one works, might turn out to be useful.

Comment: The second one is rather tricky. You needn't know how it works if you don't want to become a developer of LaTeX packages. For more information for this, see the implementation of `\xrightarrow` in `amsmath` package, and the definition of `\mapsto`.

Answer (score 15):

You may also want to try `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
      \xi \colon &L^\infty(T) \to \mathcal{L}(H^2)\\
       &\phi \xmapsto{\phantom{L^\infty(T)}} T_\phi
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like:

[image: mathtools output]

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting the post. But, found this code really shorter.

Comment: Thanks. This a nice answer. I use `mathtools` already, so I will remember this.

Comment: It looks to me like the arrow is not quite the right length here. There's a coincidence (that $\phi$ and $\rightarrow$ are about the same width) that makes it look close.