# Writing a nice function

Tags: amsmath

How to write a function mapping like this: 
**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$ \begin{matrix} f'\colon & A \to \mathbb{R} \\ & x\mapsto f(x)=x^2 \end{matrix} $
\end{document}
```

[image: dfd]

It is not alignment well.

and it must be like

[image]

Comment: Please complete the code rather than posting mere fragments, which are of much less help. How should it look? Don't use `$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: I believe http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32024/21344 has the answer you seek. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(The following code uses math examples you posted initially.)

Depending on the type of alignment you want, one of the following two solutions may work for you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

If you want flush-left alignment:
\[
f\colon \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}l} 
          X \rightarrow Y \\ 
          x\mapsto f(x)=\frac{x-1}{2} 
         \end{array}
\]

\bigskip
If the arrows have to be aligned vertically:
\[
f\colon \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}r @{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} >{\displaystyle}l} 
          X &\rightarrow& Y \\ 
          x &\mapsto& f(x)=\frac{x-1}{2} 
         \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: To align the first row of the `array` with `f\colon`, provide the `[t]` placement option after `\begin{array}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
If \verb+f\colon+ should be on the same line as \verb+X\to Y+:
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
f\colon \begin{array}[t]{ >{\displaystyle}r >{{}}c<{{}}  >{\displaystyle}l } 
          X &\to& Y \\ 
          x &\mapsto& f(x)=\frac{x-1}{2} 
         \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: can it be improved for f and X \to Y in the same line?

Comment: @LuisFelipe - Sure: Just insert `[t]` after `\begin{array}`, i.e., write `\begin{array}[t]{...}`.