# function definition: $\to$ plus $\mapsto$

Tags: math-mode

I [know](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37791) that one should use

```
$f\colon A\to B$
```

instead of

```
$f: A\to B$
```

Now I am wondering how one should write the declaration of domain and codomain of a function (i.e. f: A --> B) together with the assignment rule of the function (by which I mean a |--> f(a), where f(a) is the rule). I found the following possibilities:

1.

```
The function $f\colon A\to B : a\mapsto f(a)$ satisfies ...
```

2.

```
The function $f\colon A\to B$, $a\mapsto f(a)$ satisfies ...
```

3.

```
The function $f\colon A\to B, a\mapsto f(a)$ satisfies ...
```

4.

Using words:

```
The function $f\colon A\to B$ which is given by $a\mapsto f(a)$ satisfies ...
```

Do you know other possibilities? Which possibility do you recommend using?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your posting appears to be eliciting subjective views. Separately, have you seen the posting [Writing a nice function](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/289589/5001)?

Comment: @Mico: Mhm, the post you linked to seems to focus more on how to write tex-code which generates the definition of a function where the assignment rule is *under* the declaration of domain and codomain.

Comment: I'd use method 2.

Comment: I, too, see this more as a question on good writing style rather than on proper TeX usage. Though I am inclined to consider possibilities 1 and 3 as *wrong*, while the choice between 2 and 4 is more one of style. (Personally, I'd go for 4, but deleting “which is”.) To elaborate, I consider 1 and 3 as wrong because they smash to formulas into one.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen: I think the same, maybe  using ‘defined by’ and adding a comma before ‘satisfies’.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is a question about mathematical notation.

Comment: Following the lead of lambda calculus it would by correct to write $f=(a\mapsto f(a) )$ or even 'anonymously' $(a\mapsto f(a) ) \colon A \to b$.