# mapsto and function definition / definition environment

Tags: equations, environments, definition

Ok, these are 2 questions in one, but they are different.

1. I am trying to define a function f mapping from X to Y. So what i am doing is: open the `equation` environment and writing: `$f:X{\rightarrow}Y$`. However, after that, i would like to write below the `X{\rightarrow}Y` the following `x{\mapsto}y` since `$x{\in}X$` and `$y{\in}Y$`. But if i open another `equation` environment to write this `x{\mapsto}y` it does not get aligned with the `X{\rightarrow}Y`. So i need help. What am i supposed to do?
2. The other problem is that i what to write Definitios and theorems in the text. SO, i am using the `amsthm` package and, in the preambule, i wrote `\newtheorem{def}{Definition}`. However, when i open the def environment things go insane, because appears the single word Definition in the first page of the file and the body of the text begins only in the second page. And worse: in the place where it was supposed the Definition (and the text together it) to appear, nothing appears. So i don't know what to do.

---

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \newtheorem{defi}{Definition}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{defi}
 A set $A$ is... 
\end{defi} 
\end{document}
```

I am a beginner in LaTeX. I am sorry if it seems dumb.

Comment: For (1) what you need is the `align` instead of `equation` or math mode `$ $`. Search for `align` here, there are many examples.

Comment: For (2) is impossible to say without having some code. We need to read what you use.

Comment: Thanks, Sigur... Im am trying to write, but it the space is very short... \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{def}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{def}
A set $A$ is...
\end{def}


\end{document}

Comment: don't write as a comment, but hit the "edit" button and edit your actual question to include the code.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Ah, `def` is not a good name. Use `defi` instead. In the future, after learning more you'll see why.

Comment: Some expert, please, format the code as code. I'm not able because the numbered list. ctrl k does not work.

Comment: indeed. now it works. thanks a lot Sigur and Steven. But, for the first question i still dont have an answer

Comment: @PolianeLima, check it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32024/14757 The first piece of code: `\begin{align*}
  \xi \colon L^\infty(T) &\to \mathcal{L}(H^2)\\
  \phi &\mapsto T_\phi.
\end{align*}` from Leo Liu.